# Git has forgotten the remote repository I fetch from / push to

Tags: git, repository

This morning I went to do a git fetch and got the following error:

> fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL
>   or a remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

This used to work fine. It looks like git has forgotten the link between (all) my branches and the repository.
Typing `git remote -v` doesn't return anything.
It was working at the end of last week, and the only thing that I can think of that I have changed was installing the latest GitExtensions release. However right now I am more worried about whether there is some way I can get back the repository information.
Any ideas?

Update:
My .git/config file was empty. Although I don't know the cause, I was able to remote desktop to another computer in the company and retrieve the "remote" section of its config.
I have updated my config file, and so far it looks like it is working :-)

Update 2: 
I have also needed to relink the branches to the origin via:

```
git config branch.develop.remote origin
git config branch.develop.merge refs/heads/develop
```

etc

Comment: Do you still know the remote URL?

Comment: Do you have another repo by some chance where you cloned it to? Also, where do you have it hosted remotely? Is this hosted privately via gitosis?

Comment: @Thilo I work remotely on the other side of the world to the main team - I will need to get it from the network admin when their day starts

Comment: @Chris It is hosted on a server in the company I work for. Re other repo - good thought - I will go check my laptop, at one time I had a copy on there, but I don't know if I do anymore

Comment: @hamishmcn if it's hosted on the server in the company you work for it must most likely has openssh open setup correct? If so, do they give you access to ssh into the server? You could find the details that way via SSH or finding a server admin that could give you access to do so.

Comment: @Chris - access is via PuTTY and a VPN. Yes, I will get the server admin to send me details and re enter them, thanks

Comment: @hamishmcn alright well that sounds like that'll do it. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

1. You can take a look on .git/config  and configure it.
2. You can also make your local branch track back your remote branch by typing

   `git branch --set-upstream <localbranch> <remotebranch>`

When you type `git fetch` the local branch will fetch codes from those tracking remote branch.

Comment: Thanks, #2 fixed it for me, I was getting this error "No remote repository specified."

Comment: Can you give me an example? Like `branch --set-upstream master origin/master`?

Answer (score 7):

Seems like a very old question, but want to update to Kit Ho's answer with slight modification. Might be useful for someone.

```
git branch --set-upstream <localbranch> <remotebranch>
```

is deprecated as of git version 1.9.2. This is the correct syntax now,

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=<upstream>
```

An example would be,

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=originremote/testbranch
```

Answer (score 4):

Remote information should be stored in the .git/config file, check that file and see if it's corrupted. If it is you might have to re-add every remote you had before or do a clean checkout, if it is there, there might be a bug in the GitExtension release...

Comment: Thanks: .git/config is empty...  I am wondering now whether I accidentally cleared a field when looking through the settings after installing in.